# IOS UILocalNotifications live after my app has been deleted...how to deal with these notifications?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

I was wondering how to deal with UILocalNotifications that were created using my app but the app then got deleted. 
Lets say that after creating a few notifications, the user decides to delete the app, but i've noticed that even though the app is deleted the notifications lived and they still fire in the correct time, but this doesn't make sense to me since the app is not existant in the phone anymore.

I understand how this is possible, but i would like to know if there a way to delete such notifications when the user decides to get rid of my app?

And does this happen as well if the app is being updated?

Thanks.

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]; can be used to remove all local notification, but i was wondering how we can use this in your case. As when application is removed, i think we won't get any control in our application.

Comment: thats exactly my dilema, if the app is deleted I have no control over it, meaning my notifications are free, but still live...

Comment: can't you remove all local notification when application terminates and start those again when application is launched again?

Comment: @RIP that would defeat the purpose of the `UILocalNotification`. This sounds like a bug and should be reported to Apple as there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @Joe -you are right, this is not right way.

Comment: yeah it is possible, but i believe is not a good practice because when i tried it, it slowed the app startup way too much.

Comment: @Joe yeah i thought that too, i believed is a bug because its just logical that if your app is deleted, means the user doesnt need or wants it anymore meaning the notifications should no longer exist.

Comment: Definitely seems like a bug. I remember a bug where if the app was deleted and then re=installed, push notifications from the previously deleted version were re-initialized. Ultimately I just ended up writing some preventive code to make sure that the notifications that would fire were valid notifications.

Comment: If this was a bug, it is still happening as of today!  Oh come one big A, you can fix this bug!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use APNS (remote notifications) instead of local notifications.
This way, once your App was removed, pushed notifications will not get to the device anymore , nor to the user's attention.

At this stage you can be aware of the App's removal (using APNS feedback service) and cease your sending mechanism for that user (his push token..)

Comment: Yeah I believe that is a "safe" approach, however I would't want to get involved in that level because of the Internet connection, and the fact that it requires more coding and me knowing how Push Notification works, and these events that I am notifying are more like Alarm schedules.